# Access template variable in *ngIf

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-template

I am trying to define a template variable on an element and use its hidden attribute to identify whether the element is actually present in the DOM and then display another element based on that. But if there is a structural directive, template variable does not seem to return a value.

```
<hr class="divider" *ngIf="true" #divi>
<div *ngIf="showResendWelcomeEmailButton">
  <a *wpHasAnyPermission="[{'something': true}]" 
     #resendEmailBtn>
    Resend Welcome Email
  </a>
</div>
<div class="pull-right">
  <a #editAccountBtn>Edit Account Details</a>
</div>

rbtn: {{resendEmailBtn?.hidden}}
ebtn: {{editAccountBtn?.hidden}}
dline: {{divi?.hidden}}
```

Output is

```
rbtn:
ebtn: false
dline:
```

As you can see both the template variables on elements containing attributes `ngIf` and `wpHasAnyPermission` are not returning an values.

What I want to eventually do is to use `resendEmailBtn` and `editAccountBtn` in `ngIf` of `hr` to decide displaying the divider.

What is the best way to solve this ? I want to avoid dealing with component code. Try to solve this with in HTML.

Answer (score 10):

The variable is not available outside the element where `*ngIf` is applied.

```
<hr class="divider" *ngIf="false" #divi>
```

will be replace by

```
<template let-divi [ngIf]="false">
  <hr class="divider"  >
</template>
```

and `divi` will only be available within the `<template>` element.

You can add

```
@ViewChild('editAccountBtn') editAccountBtn:ElementRef;
```

to your components class, to make it available within the whole components template. It only has a value, when the queried element is added to the DOM. If it's within an `*ngIf` that evaluates to `false` the value will be `null`.

Comment: I'm curious how `editAccountBtn` was accessible outside. What you mentioned is applicable only to elements with structural attributes ? What would be the best way to solve my problem ?

Comment: I'm not sure if I asked the question clearly. What I wanted to do was `<hr class="divider" *ngIf="!emailAccountBtn?.hidden">` so that I can display the divider only when the button is present. I don't care about the variable of `hr` element.

Comment: thanks for taking time to respond. Just to be clear, I don't have problem accessing editAccountBtn since it does not any structural directives on it. However, resendEmailBtn is not accessible. I tried to add ViewChild for that in the component but that did not make any difference..

Comment: Sorry, was a bit late already.. With `@ViewChild()` it also only is available when `*ngIf` is `true`, otherwise the content doesn't exist and the reference is null. Did you try with `true`

Comment: `resendEmailBtn` is on a button that is true and I mean I can see the element getting displayed.