# Reference an element without ViewChild, directly in an Angular HTML template

Tags: angular

I've an image element like this:

```html
<img #imgElement *ngIf="data.image" [src]="data.image" width=200 />
```

I intend to print the dimensions of the image right below it, like

```html
{{imgElement.naturalWidth}} x {{imgElement.naturalHeight}}
```

However I get the error:

> Property 'imgElement' does not exist on type MyComponent.

Is there a way to achieve this without having a `@ViewChild('imgElement')` in the component?

Comment: The reason this does not work is that [structural directives like `*ngIf` act as template boundaries for template variables](https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables#template-variable-scope) and you cannot access a template variable outside of the boundary it was declared in unless (as your question points out) you add a `@VeiwChild` reference to it. See: [Access template variable in *ngIf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45247462/access-template-variable-in-ngif)

Comment: Makes sense, thank you @DM.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is the `*ngIf` part. Without that the element is directly referenceable.

i.e.

```html
<img #imgElement [src]="data.image" width=200 />

{{imgElement.naturalWidth}} x {{imgElement.naturalHeight}}
```

**Edit:**

As @DM mentioned, a good solution is to wrap the whole block in an `*ngIf`, e.g.,

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="data.image">
  <img #imgElement [src]="data.image" width=200 />

  {{imgElement.naturalWidth}} x {{imgElement.naturalHeight}}
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: You may want to wrap the whole block in `<ng-container *ngIf="data.image"></ng-container>` so that you don't display values until the image is loaded.

Comment: Great suggestion, thank you @DM!!